# JavaScript object strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Excuse me for a not-standart question, everything works fine, but it is still strange
On a webpage I use a datepicker from [here](http://foxrunsoftware.github.io/DatePicker/)
Here is the partial code:
HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker-calendar"></div>
```

Function for DatePicker insertion:

```
function insert_datepicker(mode)
{
    $('#datepicker-calendar').empty();  
    ...
    $('#datepicker-calendar').DatePicker({
        ...
        onChange    : function(date,el) {  
            if (mode == 1){
                doSmth1();
            }
            if (mode == 2){
                doSmth2();
            }
        }  
    });
    ...
}
```

'mode' is not a global variable and is shown as 'undefined' in console.
When I call "insert_datepicker(2)" the onChange works fine, but shouldn't there be an error when the event is triggered?
How does the function "remembers" the note?

Comment: Why should have an error?

Comment: It's a JavaScript closures. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [closure nature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) of [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures), it allows an inner function to access the variables declared in the outer scope.

In your case the `mode` variable is declared inside `insert_datepicker` function and you have an anonymous inner function for `onChange`, here the inner function will have access to the variables declared inside `insert_datepicker` as closure variables.

Answer (score 0):

`mode` is provided when you call `insert_datepicker()`. `mode` in your case, when calling `insert_datepicker(2)` is actually `2`. All datepickers attached this way will have their `mode` bound to the `mode` passed in when calling `insert_datepickers`.

When you don't pass in `mode`, it will be `undefined`. Comparing it to `1` and `2` will yield `false` and will not execute the blocks of the statements.